# pushing server time to multiple clients through websockets

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, websocket, netbeans-8

I want to push server time which should be updated continously to multiple clients using websockets.I am facing an error in netbeans log which i have given below.what i should do to push the server time to multiple client without any error.
server code:

```
package nikhil;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;

@ServerEndpoint("/jnc")
public class WebSocketClockn {


    static ScheduledExecutorService timer
            = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    private static Set<Session> allSessions;

    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

//    @OnOpen
    public void showTime(Session session) {
        allSessions = session.getOpenSessions();

        // start the scheduler on the very first connection
        // to call sendTimeToAll every second   
        if (allSessions.size() == 1) {
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> sendTimeToAll(session), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("server is running");
        }
    }

    private void sendTimeToAll(Session session) {
        allSessions = session.getOpenSessions();
        for (Session sess : allSessions) {
            try {
                sess.getBasicRemote().sendText("Local time: "
                        + LocalTime.now().format(timeFormatter));
                System.out.println("server is running");
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

client code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Getting server updates</h1>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            //window.onload = init;
            var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ServerPush/jnc");
            socket.onopen = function () {
                console.log('Opened connection ');
            }
            socket.onmessage = function (event) {
                console.log('typeof(event.data)');
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data + "<br>";
            };
            socket.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log("Error ", event);
            }
        </script>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error i am facing in netbeans log is:

14-Feb-2018 10:13:18.431 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-18] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/ServerPush] has started
14-Feb-2018 10:13:18.453 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-18] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/ServerPush] is completed
14-Feb-2018 10:13:21.572 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-19] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/ServerPush] has started
14-Feb-2018 10:13:21.598 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-19] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/ServerPush] is completed
14-Feb-2018 10:13:21.847 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-24] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error reading request, ignored
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase.doOnOpen(PojoEndpointBase.java:58)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointServer.onOpen(PojoEndpointServer.java:64)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:133)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Don't do this.  If you want time synchronization use a standard, extremely well debugged (compared to anything you could write) system like NTP.  Time sync should happen at the OS level, not at the application level.  All modern operating systems support using NTP, and come with the client software by default.  All you have to do is set up your server as a "Stratum 2" or "Stratum 3" server getting its time from one of the many time servers on the Internet.  Your server will be within milliseconds of the actual time, and so will all the clients.

Comment: Your stack clearly states a websocket misconfiguration. I'm not a Tomcat user so I checked [`PojoEndpointBase` class at line 58](https://github.com/apache/tomcat85/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/pojo/PojoEndpointBase.java). You have a `NullPointerException` there, you can start by checking if the link I provide is your implementation or not